# Scale image as background based upon user's machine screensize

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, resize, onload

I have a image (uploaded by user, cant say about the size of that). It will be used as background image for his page.
I just want to scale it to the full size of the screen. Some think like. On load find the screensize using Jquery/javascript and add that style to the background image.

PS:- There is no Y scroll on the page. And I am not concerned about the quality of the image on scaling if image size of too small.

Comment: what's wrong with css on body background?

Comment: @shevski if image is small or large it will create issues..

Comment: @shevski check Matic's answer.. download the code and check it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this jQuery plugin https://github.com/iamjpg/jQuery-Ez-Background-Resize